# Log Stacktrace of current Python Interpreter via PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to find a bug which happens from time to time on our production server, but could not be reproduced otherwise: some value in the DB gets changed in a way which I don't want it to.

I could write a PostgreSQL trigger which fires if this bug happens, and raise an exception from said trigger. I would see the Python traceback which executes the unwanted SQL statement.

But in this case I don't want to stop the processing of the request.

Is there a way to log the Python/Django traceback from within a PostgreSQL trigger?

I know that this is not trival since the DB code runs under a different linux process with a different user id.

I am using Python, Django, PostgreSQL, Linux.

I guess this is not easy since the DB trigger runs in a different context than the python interpreter.

Please ask if you need further information.

## Update

One solution might be to overwrite [connection.notices](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.notices) of psycopg2.

Comment: Have you tried `logger.exception()` in `except` block?

Comment: Instead of raising an exception you could `RAISE NOTICE ...` , which does not abort the current transaction. Don't know how to include the python stacktrace into the message body. Database EVENTs would be another possibility, but that will require more instrumentation.

Comment: @joop The difficult part is how to get the python stacktrace from within postgres.

Comment: Not clear: `I would see the Python traceback which executes the unwanted SQL statement.` You have a trigger function in PL/Python?

Comment: @joop up to now I do not execute pl/pythonu, but I could do so, if needed.

Comment: Then: why do you want to unwind the python stack from within the DBMS? They are different processes.

Comment: @joop you ask me why I want this? I try to find a not reproducible bug which happens from time to time on our production server. (In the first version of the question I had a typo. "dev" instead of "prod")

Comment: What is it that has to continue? The WSGI request or the query? Can you detect from within python that the modification happened?

Comment: @MelvynSopacua No, I can't detect this in Python, the detection happens in this case in the database.

Comment: So why is there a bug? If there's a modification happening in the database that has no effect on the python code, what is the problem? How does it manifest itself? Obviously, if you want the transaction to complete, you cannot interrupt it, and without an exception there's no python backtrace.

Comment: @MelvynSopacua I want to do **logging**. You say "without an exception there's no python backtrace.". Are you sure there is no way?

Comment: The backtrace (or the current call stack) can be examined with the `traceback` module. There is indeed no exception backtrace without an exeption, but the execution stack can always be examined using methods like `traceback.extract_stack`

Comment: @guettli short answer: there is really no way unless you pass the whole stack as a string along with every DB request. Instead we might be able to help find this specific problem. Can you give a brief idea of your tables, what value is being changed incorrectly, what sort of ORM are you using, how have you proved that this is indeed happening from the Django code and not some other process; etc?

Answer (score 3):

```
Is there a way to log the Python/Django traceback from within a PostgreSQL trigger?
```

---

No, there is not

- The (SQL) query is executed on the *DBMS-server*, and so is the code inside the trigger
- The Python code is executed on the *client* which is a different process, possibly executed by a different user, and maybe even on a different machine.

The only connection between the server (which detects the condition) and the client (which needs to perform the stackdump) is the connected socket. You could try to extend the server's reply (if there is one) by some status code, which is used by the client to stackddump itself. This will only work if the trigger is part of the current transaction, not of some unrelated process.

The other way is: massive logging. Make the DBMS write *every* submitted SQL to its logfile. This can cause huge amounts of log entries, which you have to inspect.

Comment: writing every sql statement to a log file makes no sense in this context. I would see: "Ah, there is the bad SQL statement which I am hunting at the moment". But I would have not clue where the related python code is. In this case the issue is even more complicated, since the statement alone is not enough to decide if the sql statement is the one I search. I need other row-values which are not visible in the sql statement. But I can catch this with a trigger method in postgresql. This works.

Answer (score 1):

Given this setup

```
(django/python) -[SQL connection]-> (PostgreSQL server)
```

your intuition that

> I guess this is not easy since the DB trigger runs in a different context than the python interpreter.

is correct. At least, we won't be able to do this exactly the way you want it; not without much acrobatics.

However, there are options, each with drawbacks:

- If you are using django with SQLAlchemy, you can register event listeners (either [ORM events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html) or [Core Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html)) that detect this bad SQL statement you are hunting, and log a traceback.
- Write a wrapper around your SQL driver, check for the bad SQL statement you are hunting, and log the traceback every time it's detected.
- Give every SQL transaction, or every django request, an ID (could just be some UUID in werkzeug's request-bound storage manager). From here, we gain more options:

  - Configure the logger to log this request ID everywhere, and log all SQL statements in SQLAlchemy. This lets you correlate Django requests, and specific function invocations, with SQL statements. You can do this with `echo=` in SQLAlchemy.
  - Include this request ID in every SQL statement (extra column?), then log this ID in the PostgreSQL trigger with `RAISE NOTICE`. This lets you correlate client-side activity in django against server-side activity in PostgreSQL.
- In the spirit of "Test in Production" espoused by [Charity Majors](https://twitter.com/mipsytipsy), send every request to a sandbox copy of your Django app that reads/writes a sandboxed copy of your production database. In the sandbox database, raise the exception and log your traceback.

  - You can take this idea further and create smaller "async" setups. For example, you can, for each request, trigger a async duplicate (say, with celery) of the same request that hits a DB configured with your PostgreSQL trigger to fail and log the traceback.
- Use `RAISE EXCEPTION` in the PostgreSQL trigger to rollback the current transaction. In Python, catch that specific exception, log it, then repeat the transaction, changing the data slightly (extra column?) to indicate that this is a retry and the trigger should not fail.

Is there a reason you can't SELECT all row values into Python, then do the detection in Python entirely?

Answer (score 1):

So if you're able to detect the condition after the queries execute, then you can log the condition and/or throw an exception.

Then what you need is tooling like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/).

Comment: Well, I read the question as "I have an exceptional situation, that sometimes occurs, but I don't want to halt execution, but still log the state with backtrace". Maybe I understand it wrong though.

Comment: As soon as I can detect the situation in python, then I am able to log the stacktrace (without Sentry and New Relic). The current fact: I can detect the situation in python later (but then I have no traceback of the code how did the change) or I can detect the situation in a db trigger. But then again, I don't have a traceback of the code which did the change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LISTEN+NOTIFY.

First let some daemon thread [LISTEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html) and in the db trigger you can execute a [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html).

The daemon thread receives the notify event and can dump the stacktrace of the main thread.

Comment: No, this is not perfect. It is not synchronous. There is a time gap between NOTIFY and dumping the stacktrace. The interpreter could be doing already other stuff when the stacktrace gets dumped.

Answer (score 0):

If you use psycopg2, you can use this

```
# Overwriting connetion.notices via Django
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        connection_created.connect(connection_created_check_for_notice_in_connection)

class ConnectionNoticeList(object):
    def append(self, message):
        if not 'some_magic_of_db_trigger' in message:
            return
        logger.warn('%s %s' % (message, ''.join(traceback.format_stack())))

def connection_created_check_for_notice_in_connection(sender, connection, **kwargs):
    connection.connection.notices=ConnectionNoticeList()
```