# Stacktrace of Python is cut in psycopg2 connection.notices

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am overwriting [connection.notices](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.notices) of psycopg2.

My goal is to send a notice from a PostgreSQL trigger to my application.

In python I want to write the current stacktrace to a log file to see which python code is triggering the trigger in the database.

It works, but unfortunately I can't extract the whole stacktrace.

I only get the lines below psycopg, not the above (lines of the callers).

Here is my code:

```
# Overwriting connetion.notices via Django
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        connection_created.connect(connection_created_check_for_notice_in_connection)

class ConnectionNoticeList(object):
    def append(self, message):
        if not 'some_magic_of_db_trigger' in message:
            return
        logger.warn('%s %s' % (message, ''.join(traceback.format_stack())))

def connection_created_check_for_notice_in_connection(sender, connection, **kwargs):
    connection.connection.notices=ConnectionNoticeList()
```

I see this in the logs:

```
'NOTICE:  some_magic_of_db_trigger: 17909
     File "/snap/pycharm-community/128/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner....ork/foo/apps.py", line 47, in append
      logger.warn(\'%s %s\' % (message, \'\'.join(traceback.format_stack())))
  '
```

`traceback.format_stack()` inside `ConnectionNoticeList.append()` extracts not the callers.

Is there a way to get the lines of the upper methods?

(This is related to an older question: [Log Stacktrace of current Python Interpreter via PostgreSQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873708/log-stacktrace-of-current-python-interpreter-via-postgresql-trigger))

Comment: Yeah! this is the 100000th question tagged "postgresql"!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if you look at this chart, it looks good. Soon there will be more question concerning PostgreSQL: http://sotagtrends.com/?tags=[postgresql,mysql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code works. I see the whole traceback.

I don't know why the traceback was cut in PyCharm. In production I could see the whole traceback and I could find the broken code which modified the data in way which should not happen.

Many thanks to Daniele Varrazzo who provided the hint to overwrite connection.notices:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2Bmi_8a5rij_5xchPkYPFS3moAtw9i6TrwKndynWfbJ%3DkFA4fg%40mail.gmail.com